# Can an Azure WebJob or Azure Function be triggered by Azure File Storage activity?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-files

Can an Azure WebJob or Azure Function be triggered by Azure File Storage activity ?

For example, when a file is created in folder "/todo/".

Comment: Did you check out the bindings available for Functions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-storage

Comment: Yes, and I don't see any reference to Azure File Storage, which is why I asked.

Comment: Not for the moment but you can implement your own trigger: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do not currently have any bindings for Azure Files, though we have an issue tracking that feature in our repo here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (23/12/2019) microsoft currently working on Filestorage trigger. Its in feature now.it will be available very soon.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/14)

Comment: I believe that thread only talks about "we keep asking the Azure storage team to implement a trigger"... no promises whatsever.