# WebJob access to Azure VM mapped file share

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, filesystemwatcher, azure-storage-files

I have a webjob which has a queue triggered function. But I also need another "signal". A third party OCR agent pulls files from an Azure File Share storage, performs its task, and drops it to another known location on the same file share. The file share is mapped to a virtual drive on an Azure VM. The agent runs in the same VM, so it has access to the virtual drive.

My issue is that I need to sync between the moment that the message in the queue arrives and the moment that the file has been dropped in the output location.
I have no control over the agent, and there is no option to run a script upon completion.

The incoming message simply signals the fact that the file has been picked up by the agent.

My question is this: in the webjob, can i use something like FileSystemWatcher to monitor the network path mapped on the VM, so that I can wait until the file has been dropped, and then continue with whatever processing I need to perform?

Comment: Maybe we could use FileTrigger to do that, more info please refer to another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41289992/azure-webjob-file-storage-activity-trigger-alternative?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seems AppService
[supports SMB protocol which utimately make \network share work. Hence no WebJob](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#restricted-outgoing-ports)