# Is there any trigger for Azure File Share in azure functions or azure logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I created file share in the azure storage account after that I mount the file share with my windows pc. Next I uploaded the files into file share drive for example (Z://), but whenever I uploaded files into OnPremise file share drive, then I want to trigger either logic app or azure function automatically and give the file/image to computer vision api and store the response into azure SQL database.

For that I followed the below documentations as

[Extract Text From Images Using Computer Vision API And Azure Function](http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/extract-text-from-images-using-computer-vision-api-and-azure-function)

[Computer Vision](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)

But those are related to azure blob storage, but not an azure file share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is no trigger for Azure File Share.

Here is a similar post, refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266396/can-an-azure-webjob-or-azure-function-be-triggered-by-azure-file-storage-activit). This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20324680-add-trigger-for-azure-file-storage), you could vote it.

Comment: Thanks Joy, can you please tell me is there any alternative way to do the same functionality.

Comment: @pradeep How about azure blob storage?

Comment: Joy, I did the same functionality using blob storage, it's working fine. But my client asked to use  azure file share.

Comment: Joy, Is it possible to implement the same functionality using `External file trigger` in azure functions.

Comment: I am not sure, because the `External file trigger` still in the experiment. I think you could mark it as answer to close the post, and ask for the workaround in another one, it will be easier for others to find it.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option is to add diagnostic setting to capture *storage write* logs and stream it to an event hub. And then you can have an Azure Function or Logic App to act on the events written to Event Hub. Here is an [article](https://marcustee.medium.com/azure-file-share-trigger-actions-after-new-files-created-c4c95aea6540) explaining this approach.